# Django and Python Script Integration :(

Tags: javascript, python, html, linux, django

On my site I have some buttons that when clicked I want them to launch my python script which reaches out to some of my servers and writes to a file.

I see plenty of posts online that say its easy but none actually give you steps as to what needs to be done

I have a basic html page and the button section looks like the below

```
<td><a href="javascript:alert('Working on it!');"<button type="button" id="myButton1" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off">DO IT</button>
```

If someone could tell me how I can get the DO IT button to launch my .py i would be forever grateful

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand. If you already have a basic site, you know how to write URLs and views. Views are just Python; you can import your function and run it from there.

Comment: Are you familiar with making AJAX requests? If not, I think it would be good to look for tutorials that explain how you can use Javascript to make requests to your Django application's different views. I have used this tutorial in the past and found it helpful. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: what i mean is i am not sure where to start .. i.e go to views.py and do this, go to url.py and do this, open your html and add this to the section for the button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your Python code inside Django, something like the following should work (you'll probably want to add error handling, show some feedback when the request is sent and when the response is received, maybe send some data to the server etc.).

First, your JavaScript to add an event listener to the button and send a request a server when it is clicked (change the request URL to correspond to your server address, Django app and view URL):

```
var button = document.querySelector('#myButton1');

button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8000/myapp/button_clicked/');
    request.onload = function () {
        console.log('Server response recieved.');
    }
    request.send();
});
```

Then, in urls.py for the relevant app (`myapp` above):

```
...
from . import views

url_patterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^button_clicked/', views.button_clicked),
]
```

And finally, in views.py for the same app:

```
...
def button_clicked(request):
    # Here, you insert the Python code you want to run when the button is clicked.
    ...
```

Comment: For the JS piece do I add that in to my html file?

Comment: For example, inside <script> tags in that case. Or in a separate JS file.

Comment: Perfect, I'll give it a go... Thank you  bey much b

Comment: no, still no joy ... just says

Not Found: /myapp/button_clicked/
[02/Oct/2017 04:15:42] "GET /myapp/button_clicked/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2541
Not Found: /myapp/button_clicked/
[02/Oct/2017 04:15:46] "GET /myapp/button_clicked/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2541